# Netgear N300 WNA3100 Install Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking, drivers, netgear

I've never used Ubuntu before so I am completely lost with what to do.

I bought a Netgear N300 (WNA3100) wireless adapter card a few months ago after
my old card stopped working.  I decided to dualboot my computer a few weeks ago and I've come across a few issues, this being the most important.

It works perfectly fine on my Windows 7 install, but not on Ubuntu.
I'm using 13.04.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a lot of problems also.  After I finally got it working it turns out the steps are:

1) Install Wine (to extract the drivers from the manufacturer's download).  If you already have the drivers folder from a different installation you don't need to install Wine.

2) Install the ndiswrapper modules (ndiswrapper-dkms ndisgtk ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-source ndiswrapper-utils-1.9).

3) Grab the drivers folder (ie. WNA3100).  Go to that folder. Run the commands (to load the driver):

```
$ sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
$ sudo ndiswrapper -i [driver]  # (moste likely named "bcmwlhigh5.ini"
```

Details and troubleshooting can be found at:
http://faq.apollo3.com/ljames/ubuntu/networksupport/

Those steps should work for most USB network adapters.